# Convert a vector to data.frame, one column for each unique value

Tags: r, vector, matrix, indexing, dataframe

We are given a vector, like this:

```
x <- c(1,2,1,5,2,1,2,5,1)
```

What we need is a `data.frame` say `y` having number of rows equal to `length(x)` and number of columns equal to `length(unique(x))`, that means one column per unique item in `x`, such that `y[i,j]==TRUE` if and only if the `i`th element of `x` is the `j`th unique item of `x` (assigned to column `j`):

```
y <- data.frame("1"=x==1, "2"=x==2, "5"=x==5, check.names=F)
```

A simple way to perform this is:

```
y <- setNames(data.frame(sapply(unique(x), function(i) x==i)), unique(x))
```

Do you have a better idea (i.e. a particular function)?

Comment: Is there something about your approach that you are unhappy with?

Comment: @AnandaMahto having sapply it might be not as efficient as yours, and more particularly i wanted to learn the straightforward R solution for this demand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can live with a binary representation instead of a logical representation of your data, I would just use `table`:

```
y <- table(seq_along(x), x)
```

To get a `data.frame`, use `as.data.frame.matrix`:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(y)
#   1 2 5
# 1 1 0 0
# 2 0 1 0
# 3 1 0 0
# 4 0 0 1
# 5 0 1 0
# 6 1 0 0
# 7 0 1 0
# 8 0 0 1
# 9 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using `outer`?

```
outer( x , unique(x) , `==` )
#      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [6,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
# [9,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Obviously finishing it all off would be wrapping it like so...

```
setNames( data.frame( outer( x , unique(x) , `==` ) ) , unique( x ) )
```